# Running tinymce after an Ajax webmethod is executed

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce

I have an Ajax webmethod that returns the overriden culture from a basepage (cs). I want to use the culture value for the tinymce "language" and "directionilty". In other words I want tinymce to wait for the Ajax method to return the culture value before the textarea is initiated on the page.

I placed tinymce.init inside the Ajax success but that didn't work.

So my question is, what's the best approach to force tinymce to wait for the webmethod to return the culture value before tinymce displays the textarea on the page???

Here is the webmethod that returns the overriden culture from the server.

```
var pageLanguage = 'en';
var directionalityVal = 'ltr'

$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/UserControls/ucFunctions.aspx/pageLanguageStr",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        pageLanguage = data.d;
        if (pageLanguage == 'ar') directionalityVal = 'rtl';                        
       }
   }) 
});
```

And here is my tinymce.init:

```
tinymce.init({
    language: pageLanguage, //this value depends on the Ajax webmethod
    directionality: directionalityVal, //this value depends on the Ajax webmethod

    formats: {
        underline: { inline: 'u', exact: true }
    },
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: false,
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "undo,redo",
    encoding: "xml",
    selector: "#blogTextBox, #recipeTextBox, #ingredientsTextBox",
    content_css: "/css/tinymce.css",
    editor_css: "/css/tinymce.css",
    toolbar: 'myToolbar | bold italic underline | bullist numlist | undo redo | link',

    plugins: 'myToolbar wordcount link paste',
    paste_as_text: true,
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('SaveContent', function (ed) {
            ed.content = ed.content.replace(/&#39/g, "&apos");
        });
    },
});

tinymce.PluginManager.add('myToolbar', function (editor, url) {
    editor.addButton('myToolbar',
        {
            title: '',
            image: '/Images/Design/icon-image4.png',
            onclick: function () { openAlbum("text"); }
        });
});
```

Comment: it should work with your `tinymce.init` in your success method as long as the `tinymce.PluginManger...` is also in the success method but that'll be ugly. Can you confirm it works, then we'll make it read better.

Comment: No it doesn't work. The textarea is not initiated on the page.....

Comment: is the ajax call a success ?

Comment: Yes the Ajax call is success.... I did alert(data.d) and the culture was there...

Comment: The textarea is not initiated on the page when tinymce.init and PluginManger are inside the success method...